# Time difference in day based on specific condition in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Tenancy_ID  Unit_ID           Unit_Create_Date           Tenancy_Start_Date
1           A                 2012-09-06 13:34:15        2012-09-08 11:34:14
2           A                 2012-09-06 13:34:15        2013-04-08 11:34:13
3           B                 2012-09-01 11:34:15        2012-09-21 11:34:15
4           B                 2012-09-01 11:34:15        2012-09-11 11:34:13
5           C                 2012-06-02 13:34:15        2012-09-08 11:34:16
3           C                 2012-06-02 13:34:15        2012-06-21 11:34:15
5           A                 2012-09-09 10:32:17        2012-11-08 11:34:18
```

I would like find out the Time difference in days from first Unit_Create_Date to first Tenancy_Start_Date for each unit.

Expected Output:

```
Unit_ID           Time_Difference_in_Days
A                 2
B                 10
C                 19
```

Steps:

For Unit_ID = A,

There are two Unit_Create_Date such as 2012-09-06 13:34:15 and 2012-09-09 10:32:17 among that the earliest(first) one is 2012-09-06 13:34:15.

Similarly There are three Tenancy_Start_Date for Unit_ID = A, such as 2012-09-08 11:34:14, 2013-04-08 11:34:13 and 2012-11-08 11:34:18 among these earliest one is 2012-09-08 11:34:14.

So the Time difference in days between  2012-09-08 11:34:14 and 2012-09-06 13:34:15 is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `groupby` and `min` after converting the columns to `.dt.date`

```
m = (df.assign(Unit_Create_Date = df['Unit_Create_Date'].dt.date
       ,Tenancy_Start_Date=df['Tenancy_Start_Date'].dt.date)
      .groupby('Unit_ID')['Unit_Create_Date','Tenancy_Start_Date'].min())

final = (m['Tenancy_Start_Date'].sub(m['Unit_Create_Date'])
        .dt.days.to_frame('Time_Difference_in_Days').reset_index())
```

---

```
  Unit_ID  Time_Difference_in_Days
0       A                        2
1       B                       10
2       C                       19
```

Note: if the datetime columns are `dtype` object , convert to datetime first.

Comment: added new question pls look into this during your free time
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63323668/append-a-column-from-one-df-to-another-based-on-the-date-column-on-both-dfs-pa