# Compute time difference in pandas based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following problem. My data has this structure:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

input = {
    "Name": ["Tom", "Tom", "nick", "krish", "krish", "jack", "krish"],
    "Age": [20, 20, 21, 19, 19, 18, 19],
    "Time": [
        "2021-09-23 00:01:00",
        "2021-09-24 00:02:00",
        "2021-09-23 00:01:00",
        "2021-09-23 00:01:00",
        "2021-09-23 00:10:00",
        "2021-09-23 00:01:00",
        "2021-09-25 00:03:00",
    ],
    "Value": [1, 5, 1, 1, 17, 2, 8],
}

df_input = pd.DataFrame(input)
```

I would like to calculate difference in minutes based on:

1. `Name`
2. and `Value` starts with 1 and ends with 9 or 17.

Desired output is:

```py
output = {
    "Name": ["Tom", "Tom", "nick", "krish", "krish", "jack", "krish"],
    "Age": [20, 20, 21, 19, 19, 18, 19],
    "Time": [
        "2021-09-23 00:01:00",
        "2021-09-24 00:02:00",
        "2021-09-23 00:01:00",
        "2021-09-23 00:01:00",
        "2021-09-23 00:10:00",
        "2021-09-23 00:01:00",
        "2021-09-25 00:03:00",
    ],
    "Value": [1, 5, 1, 1, 17, 2, 8],
    "Diff_hours": [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, # becuase no 9 or 17 at the end in Value
         9, # because 2021-09-23 00:01:00 minus 2021-09-23 00:10:00
         9,
         np.NaN, # because neither 1 at beginning and 9 or 17 at the end in Value
         9  
    ],
}

df_output = pd.DataFrame(output)
```

I found this, but it did not help me: [Time difference in day based on specific condition in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909668/time-difference-in-day-based-on-specific-condition-in-pandas)

Comment: I believe you care about age not value. because on row 3(starting with 0) value does not end with 9 or 17.

Comment: str(row['value'])[0]=='1'and(str(row['value'])[-1]=='9' or str(row['value'])[-2:]=='17')
Is this your desired conditioning statement?

Comment: Moreover, on 3rd row, how did you calculate 9?

Comment: @FatemehSangin on the row 3 there is NaN, And I care about Value, not age. Only name krish has 1 and 17 in value a and the difference between is 9 hours. Is it clear now?

Comment: NO, firstly, i said 3rd row(with 0-based indexing, which is namely the 4th row). Secondly, the difference is in minute not in hour.

Comment: @FatemehSangin Ah. ok. So `krish` has 1 in `value` in 2021-09-23 00:01:00 (row 3). Moreover.  `krish` has 17 in `value` in 2021-09-23 00:10:00 (row 4). Is it clear?

Comment: Yes, all clear, thanks. The only thing is that the difference is in minutes, not in hours, see?

Comment: @FatemehSangin yes, I already made an edit, thanks

Comment: What if for a given name, there is only one row existing with value of 17 (start with 1 and end with 17) or 19(start with 1 and end with 9)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239913/discussion-between-vojtam-and-fatemeh-sangin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I come with, but there might be better one:

```py
help = df_input[["Name", "Time", "Value"]]
help = help[(help["Value"] == 1 ) | (help["Value"] == 9 ) | (help["Value"] == 17 ) ]

help["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(help["Time"])
help['diff'] = help.sort_values(['Name','Time']).groupby('Name')['Time'].diff()

help['diff'] = help['diff'].fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))
help['diff'] = help['diff'].dt.total_seconds().div(60).astype(int)
help = help[help["diff"] != 0][["Name", "diff"]]


df_output = df_input.merge(
    help, how="left", on="Name"
)

print(df_output)
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this code and don't hesitate to ask for more clarification:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
def check(df):
    startMet= False
    endMet = False
    start = -1
    end = -1
    for row_idx in range(df.shape[0]):
        if(not(startMet) and str(df.iloc[row_idx,3])[0]=="1"):
            startMet = True
            start = row_idx
        if(not(endMet) and ( str(df.iloc[row_idx,3])[-1]=='9' or str(df.iloc[row_idx,3])[-2:]=='17') ):
            endMet = True
            end = row_idx
    if startMet and endMet:
        if start==end:
            return None
        delta = dt.strptime(df.iloc[end,2], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")- dt.strptime(df.iloc[start,2], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        seconds = delta.total_seconds()
        minutes = (seconds//60)%60
        return int(minutes)
    else:
        return None
for name in names:
    df_input.loc[df_input['Name']==name, "Diff_hours"]=check(df_input.loc[df_input['Name']==name, :])
```

`df_input`this gives you the exact output that you wanted.